# Linux printing issue with LPR command

Tags: linux, printing

while printing with `lpr`command from linux, I am getting error

```
lpr: Error - scheduler not responding! -Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of googling tells me that if you

delete the ServerName line in

```
/etc/cups/client.conf
```

and it will work.